# Blacklisting specific addresses on token::transfer

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.token

I've issued a token using eosio.token standard contract. I want to prevent transfers to a number of specific accounts, for a limited time. Since it is temporary, I think I can simply hardcode the assertions into the contract, something like:

```
eosio_assert( to != "thisaccount1"_n, "Transfer prevented" );
eosio_assert( to != "thisaccount2"_n, "Transfer prevented" );
eosio_assert( to != "thisaccount3"_n, "Transfer prevented" );
```

inside the token::transfer method.

I know it looks quick'n'dirty, but would that work? And could it have any side effects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would certainly work, but hard-coding the accounts as blacklist may not be the ideal way to do it. Since in order to change them, you would have to redeploy your code everytime you want to modify the list.

I would suggest getting a new table with the blacklist accounts, and modify the details in the table and check it in your contract rather than modifying the token contract itself

Comment: I agree using a table is the right way, but this will only be active for a few days, and then it'll be completely removed, so I'm going with quick'n'dirty.

Comment: sounds reasonable enough ;)